# Determine a layout based on column number

Tags: templating, layout

Okay, I want to create a Matrix based layout like this:

```
| x | x | x |
| x |   y   |
|   y   | x |
```

`X` is a 1/3 column and `Y` is a 2/3 column.

I want to activate the size `Y` with a lightswitch.

The problem is: If I have `| x | x |   y   |` the layout will blow up because there are too many columns so when the column amount is 3/3 I want to create a new row so all is nice and tidy.

How do I solve this?

My idea was to add a number to each column and when the maximum number is reached, there will be a new row.

That code doesn't work. I just want to show the idea.

```
{% set x = 33.33 %}
{% set y = 66.66 %}

{% for block in entry.this %}
  {% if x + y = 100 %}<div class="row">{% endif %}
    {# content #}
  {% if x + y = 100 %}</div>{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

If I can get all variables and add them up it should be possible. But how do I get the variables from each iteration.

Anybody know what I'm talking about? Other solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about we have a matrix, with block types `x` and `y`. Then you can test for block type in your loop:

```
{% for block in entry.this %}
  {% switch block.type %}
  {% case 'x' %}
    ...
  {% case 'y' %}
    ...
  {% endswitch %}
{% endfor %}
```

Another issue is that `33.33` + `66.66` = `99.99`, which is never going to be equal to `100`. (Also, the test for equality is `==`: `{% if x + y == 100 %}`). So let's use x = 1, and y = 2, for a maximum column width of 3. Here's the code:

```
{% set thisRowLength = 0 %}
{% set thisBlockLength = 0 %}
<div class="row">
  {% for block in entry.this %}

    {# how long is this block? #}
    {% switch block.type %}
    {% case 'x' %}
      {% set thisBlockLength = 1 %}
    {% case 'y' %}
      {% set thisBlockLength = 2 %}
    {% endswitch %}

    {# start a new row if necessary #}
    {% if thisRowLength + thisBlockLength > 3 %}
      </div><div class="row">
      {% thisRowLength = 0 %}
    {% endif %}

    {# now we know it fits, output this block #}
    {{ block.content }}
    {% set thisRowLength = thisRowLength + thisBlockLength %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

You will end up with an empty `<div class="row"></div>` if there are no matrix blocks. If that will be a problem, test for it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building rows, how about building your layout with inline-block elements or flexbox elements with the flex-wrap property set, to make your elements wrap automatically.